# Is asp.net webapi ideal for image processing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am just starting with hybrid mobile development. I want to develop an app where user can upload a picture taken from the mobile device camera and apply any kind of image customizing on server side (resizing and combine it with other images) and finally let the user download the new image to her device. My question is: is asp.net webapi ideal or there are another technology more suitable for this kind of work?

thanks

Comment: I had two answers and now there is only one. What happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net is a good choice for that, but most other server-side languages/technologies are just as good.